# Why won't the ForeColor of this label visibly change when altered in a loop?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am making a form that has groups of controls that I want to visibly enable/disable with a related toggle button (let's call them Group Toggles). Each group has a different variety of control types, so I made a common procedure to handle the toggling:

```
'constants for control ForeColors
Public Enum LabelForeColor
    Default = 8355711
    Off = 14277081
End Enum

Public Enum ListForeColor
    Default = 4210752
    Off = 12566463
End Enum

Public Sub EnableControl(Ctrl As Control, Enabled As Boolean)
    With Ctrl
        Select Case Ctrl.ControlType
            Case acLabel
                If Enabled Then .ForeColor = LabelForeColor.Default Else .ForeColor = LabelForeColor.Off
                Debug.Print "LABEL", .ForeColor

            Case acListBox
                If Enabled Then .ForeColor = ListForeColor.Default Else .ForeColor = ListForeColor.Off
                .Enabled = Enabled
                Debug.Print "LIST", .ForeColor

            Case acCommandButton
                .Enabled = Enabled
                Debug.Print "BUTTON", "NA"

            Case acCheckBox
                .Enabled = Enabled
                Debug.Print "CHECK", "NA"

            Case Else
                Debug.Print "Control [" & .Name & "] is not of a type that EnableControl can handle."

        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Each group of controls is represented by a collection. When the form is loaded, every control with a particular tag property is added to the corresponding collection. The Group Toggles are not added to any collection and instead have event procedures that look like this:

```
Private Sub ToggleGroup1_AfterUpdate()
    Dim State As Boolean
    'a public function that converts the toggle button's value to a boolean
    State = FormCommon.ToggleButtonState(ToggleGroup1.Value)

    Dim iCtrl As Control
    For Each iCtrl In Controls_ByPlant
        FormCommon.EnableControl iCtrl, State
    Next iCtrl
End Sub
```

When I click on a GroupToggle, all of the controls in the corresponding group visibly change appropriately, *except for the labels*. After an hour of troubleshooting, here's what I know:

- The `ForeColor` property of the label *does* change, but not visibly.
- When I call `EnableControl` on a label outside of a loop, the label visibly changes.

  - It doesn't matter if I pass the label object specifically to the subroutine or if I pass it from its group collection; the change is visible in both cases
- If I toggle-disabled a label as part of the Group Toggle event and then call `EnableControl` specifically on that label to try to disable it again, there is no visible change (probably because the `ForeColor` property is already set to the "off" color)
- Turning screen updating off with `Application.Echo` while the Group Toggle event runs and then turning it back on at the end of the event does not make a difference.
- Making the Group Toggle event run with a `For i = 1 to .Count` instead of a `For Each` does not make a difference.
- This problem also occurs when changing a different visual property instead, such as ForeTint.
- (Per comments) `Repaint` does not make a difference
- (Per comments) `DoEvents` does not make a difference

Why is this happening?

(First ever question, so apologies if I messed something up in the post)

Comment: Use Conditional Formatting, not VBA.

Comment: @June7 I'm not sure I know what you're talking about.

Comment: Bing: Access Conditional Formatting. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-6BA9E9FA-4347-4183-B335-44E43B05E22F

Comment: However, available only for textbox and combobox. If form is in Continuous or Datasheet view, VBA won't work because all instances of a control are affected. I have used VBA to modify properties of controls on Single view form. I will have to look at your code some more later.

Comment: @June7: I'm pretty sure this is about a single form.

Comment: I ran your code on a `For Each iCtrl In Me.Controls` loop, and it worked for all specified controls, including labels. Access 2010 here. You might try a `myForm.Repaint` after the loop. Can you post a screenshot of your form?

Comment: did adding "DoEvents" within your loop help at all?

Comment: @Andre At your suggestion, I tried both `Me.Repaint` in the event procedure and `Ctrl.Parent.Repaint` in the common procedure (`Ctrl.Parent.Parent.Repaint` for labels, which are bound to other controls). Neither worked. I will try to get you a screenshot of my form.

Comment: @krishKM At your suggestion, I put `DoEvents` in the event procedure. It did not change anything.

Comment: TBH, I didn't really expect it to do anything. :( If the problem irks you enough, and you can create a sample database with the form, the necessary code and some sample data (if needed), I'd have a look at it.

Comment: add doevents after changing .forecolor value and tell me if that worked?

Comment: @krishKM I did as you suggested. Nothing changed...

Comment: @Andre [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/en81duie7te560y/ToggleGroupSample.accdb?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was interesting, but somewhat anticlimactic.

Your code does work for the labels, but what happens is this:

- All labels are associated with input controls (as it is usual)
- When you deactivate a group, you disable the input controls (`.Enabled = Enabled`)
- This automatically sets the associated labels to a (system defined) light gray text color which cannot be changed.
- This "disabled label" color is very similar to your `LabelForeColor.Default` color, so it is hard to see the change when toggling. But it does change.

Change your color constants to make the effect more visible:

```vb
Public Enum LabelForeColor
    Default = vbRed ' 8355711
    ' the "Off" color is never visible, unless you add an un-associated label to a group
    Off = vbBlue ' 14277081
End Enum
```

[image]

Edit: your test code `FormCommon.EnableControl iCtrl, False` works, because it only affects the label, but doesn't disable its associated list box.